# casting in an object based on an incoming string

Tags: java, class, templates, casting

Can this be done in Java

```
public <T> T[] getAttr(String s) {
    Object x = getSomething(s);
    com.class."s"[] y = (com.class."s"[]) x;
    return y;
}
```

I realise this is all very rough. But the basic principle can this be achieved in Java.

EDIT:

Guys I already have the object I wish return `x`. I just want it returned as the correct type. I.e the class version of `s`

Comment: Not quite sure what you want, but from what I understand, it looks like you'll need reflection.

Comment: I want to set the type of the object based on an string parameter. Can this be done. Basically a similar function if string had a function `String.toClass`

Comment: @adarshr it is Object the method getSomething returns Object. Why would it matter if it was an array or not I have just realised I typo in the casting on the right side of equals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

get the class

```
Class<?> theClazz = Class.forName("com.class."+s);
```

create an array of the specified runtime type and length:

```
java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(theClazz, length);
```

You are going to have to suppress some warnings about type-safety. There is no way around that if you really want to go from Strings. Maybe pass in a Class object instead, then it can be made type-safe.

Answer (score 1):

This is very type unsafe way to do this:

```
return (T[]) java.reflect.Array.newInstance( Class.forName( "com.class" + s, n );
```

Answer (score 1):

This would be perfectly legal

```
public class Test {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        Object o = new String("abc123");

        try {
            String s = cast(o, "java.lang.String");
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static <T> T cast(Object o, String clazz) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        return (T) Class.forName(clazz).cast(o);
    }
}
```

The question is, what would you have accomplished? Nothing really. Sure, you can cast an object based on a string (Class.cast(...)), but you would still need to declare your output as a String at compile time. Difference between runtime type and compile-time type. And java is strongly typed. The compiler will not attempt to convert your string to a type, and generics are strictly compile-time.

Comment: Ok let me explain in a little more detail. My method `getSomething` method takes in a string which is an attribute name a calls the getter on the associated object being introspected and returns the value as an `Object` of these objects are arrays of Objects. In order to be able to do something useful with them I will need to cast them to not only the array but the type too.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be achieved using [JAVA Reflection API](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/), although I been coming across numerous warning to be careful using it, because it could lead to difficult to foreseen effects.